# Can I bring tobacco, betel nut and edible lime in Saudi Arabia from India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, saudi-arabia

I want to bring above mentioned items in following quantities :

- Tobacco - 500g.
- Betel Nut - 1 Kg.
- Edible lime - 500g.

Can I bring those items with me directly ? Or do I need some kind of pre-approval letter to bring those?

Comment: Chewing tobacco is banned for import

Comment: No. I am also unsure about limits in quantity. I only know chewing tobacco and similar are forbidden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> - Tobacco - 500g

500g is the max allowed quantity of any tobacco product other than cigarettes and cigars. However, chewing tobacco is prohibited [Source 1 (in Arabic)](https://www.customs.gov.sa/ar/node/1040), [Source 2 (in Arabic)](https://www.customs.gov.sa/ar/general/Prohibited-goods#)

> - Betel Nut - 1 Kg.

Prohibited. [Source (in Arabic)](https://www.customs.gov.sa/ar/general/Prohibited-goods#)

> - Edible lime - 500g

No specific law for this product, but in general importing factory sealed food products is allowed, except if it contains a prohibited content.

Comment: Other than 200 cigarettes and 24 cigars, Nice Answer NDT