# Betel nuts on Saudia Airlines to Paris

Tags: france, food-and-drink, saudi-airlines

I'm traveling to Paris on Saudia Airlines and want to carry 5-10kg of betel nuts. Is it allowed?

Comment: Are you starting your journey in Saudi Arabia, or connecting from another country through Saudi Arabia?

Comment: In carry on or checked luggage? Why not buy them when you arrive? https://www.douane.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/2021-03/10/travellers-what-kinds-of-food-and-plants-can-you-bring-with-you.pdf

Comment: Will they be opened at all?

Comment: @mlc OP wants to bring the nuts to Paris, not Saudi.

Comment: Do you want to appear on one of those programs like Border Security: [Australia's or any other country name] Front Line? If no, go get some legal professional advise about transporting a commercial amount of any legal (in some places) drug.

Answer (score 17):

On arrival in the EU, be sure you comply with [the regulations for bringing food into France](https://www.douane.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/2021-03/10/travellers-what-kinds-of-food-and-plants-can-you-bring-with-you.pdf). In particular, it seems that you are required to have a plant health certificate from the country of the nuts' origin. There are also [additional regulations](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0166&from=EN) to comply with if you are bringing betel leaves in addition to the nuts. If in doubt, bring the nuts for inspection through the red ("goods to declare") channel when you arrive for confirmation that you have complied with the regulations.

However, [it is illegal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129170/can-i-bring-tobacco-betel-nut-and-edible-lime-in-saudi-arabia-from-india) to bring betel into Saudi Arabia. It is not quite clear if this prohibition also applies to goods merely in transit, but I would very much advise against taking the risk. Better to avoid the chance of breaking the laws of such a strict regime if at all possible.